# ¿Como decodificar huffman adaptativo?

Tags: imagen, algoritmos, msdos

Estoy tratando de descomprimir lo que seria un archivo PNG, he llegado a la parte de obtener los datos ya comprimido del apartado IDAT, segun entiendo estos datos se encuentran decodificados en un Huffman adatativo, he investigado ya en ciertas paginas sobre el tema pero me he topado con el problema de no saber como ordenar los datos, pues segun he visto hay que ordenarlos en base en:

> 16, 17, 18, 0, 8, 7, 9, 6, 10, 5, 11, 4, 12, 3, 13, 2, 14, 1, 15

mas sin embargo se limitan en mostrar una cadena ya ordenada, los datos que he podido obtener son:

> HLIT = 286, HDIST = 27 y HCEN = 14

en base a lo que seria HCEN he obtenido una serie de bits agrupado cada 3 bits, los cuales estan de la siguiente forma:

```
[ 110, 6 ][ 110, 6 ][ 101, 5 ][ 100, 4 ][ 011, 3 ][ 011, 3 ][ 000, 0 ][ 011, 3 ][ 000, 0 ][ 010, 2 ][ 000, 0 ][ 011, 3 ][ 000, 0 ][ 011, 3 ]
```

hay que resaltar que a la par de los bits se encuentra su correspondiente valor en decimal.

En si lo que busco es la forma correcta de ordenar los bits y de como descomprimir los datos restantes.

**Actualizacion**

Bueno no se si esta bien lo que he hecho pero note que la secuencia de 16, 17, 18, 0, 8, 7, 9, 6, 10, 5, 11, 4, 12, 3, 13, 2, 14, 1, 15 corresponde a las nuevas posición de los elementos pues al parecer los bits estan desordenados, por lo que el bit que vale por 6 en la primera posicion ahora estaria en la posicion 16 de una nueva cadena claro que iniciando a contar desde 0